# How to fill a zip uneven length lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, beautifulsoup, missing-data

I am parsing a file with Beautifulsoup and building 2 lists as  values in a dictionary.

```
degree = []
for h5 in soup.find_all("info", "degree"):
    degree.append(h5.text.encode("utf-8"))

print degree

major = []
for h5 in soup.find_all("info", "major"):
    major.append(h5.text.encode("utf-8"))

print major
```

Sometimes the length of each list is different (a value is missing).
How do I make sure that I detect this before building my dictionary so I can add a `"None"` value?

I tried using:

```
for k in set(major).difference(degree):
    degree[k] = "None"
```

But it did not work ok.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I hope that my question is clear enough.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create your dictionary by `degree` and `major`?

Comment: Padraic, I would not know which value to replace ex-ante.

Comment: Kasra, the dictionary will include the degree and major lists as values.

Comment: Kasra, degree and major will feed the values of the dict (first value of degree with first value of major, and so on). When a value is missing the pair is incomplete.

Comment: @Diego so whats the keys of your dict?

Comment: Thank you Padraic, I am parsing a very long html document. Could you elaborate on what kind of code you would use?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thank you so much for the edition of the question.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham since I am new to SO, I noticed that you downvoted  and unupvoted me, is there anything I did wrong? Thank you for clarifying this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all so much for your inputs and patience.
Based on the suggestion made by Kasra (which I voted) I found this solution (I added institution as the key of the dictionary:

```
educ_list = []
data = {x : [y, z] for x,y,z in zip(inst, degree, major)}
for i in itertools.izip_longest(inst, degree, major):
    educ_list.append(i)
print educ_list
```

Comment: @Diego.you do realise that your data will have no relation and will be zipped in an arbitrary order?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, the final code works in the desired order for me. I added institution as the key in the dictionary. Here it is so you can doublecheck it. Am I missing anything?  data = {x : [y, z] for x,y,z in zip( inst, degree, major)}
for i in itertools.izip_longest(inst, degree, major): print i
print data

Comment: My point is you say there is no relation between the elements  so I don't see how using set.difference fits into your question. If there are no common elements the difference would be the whole list

Comment: I understand your point which is absolutely correct. I am not using set.difference. My final code is the one posted in this answer (and seems to be working fine). Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: so inst and major  have a relationship in the same order but degree and inst have no relationship is that correct?

Comment: There is a relationship between inst, degree and major. There is a tuple for each education experience. Please see the new updated code above and tell me what you think. Thanks @PadraicCunningham for your patience with me.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, since I am new to SO, I might not understand the etiquette very well. Should I click on this answer now as the correct one or leave it like it is? Thanks.

Comment: yes you can accept your own answer. My point is that if there is a relationship then zipping and filling missing values with None will mean you don't necessarily zip the correct elements together, the None's get added to the end when you exhaust the shorter list. so if element 3 from one list has no match in the second list, from there on the values will not align.  The set.difference seemed like some attempt to align values. When you ask a question adding a small  input and expected output sample will help make your intent clear which will help others experiencing a similar problem

Comment: It would be very easy do all you want using just beautifulSoup in a single pass over the element that major and degree appear.

Comment: I understand your point now. I have been trying to find an esier and more succint solution but unfortunately I could not. Thanks a lot @PadraicCunningham !

Comment: if you can share the url I will show you how. If you just want to zip two  uneven length lists together and don't care about relationships you should probably edit your title to reflect this

Comment: Thank you @PadraicCunningham for the orientation about adding a small input and expected output sample.

Comment: No worries, as the saying goes *a picture paints a thousand words*, seeing exactly what is coming in and what it should look  like after processing often clears up a lot of ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If the `degree` and `major` values are associated with each other in the source HTML, it's probably better to find the next highest DOM element that contains both for each iteration, then iterate over those and fill both at once in the same loop.

Comment: I would need to see the structure of the source HTML; parsing code is always heavily dependent on that. Also, I assume that the desired mapping from degree to major is 1:1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.izip_longest` for create your dictionary , for example :

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> degree=[1,2,3]
>>> major=['a','b','c','d']
>>> dict(izip_longest(major,degree))
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': None}
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham there is no need to match i suggest this based on OP's request

Comment: Thank you Kasra, it outputs major as key and degree as value. I would need both to be the values of a dict.

Comment: Kasra, thanks for the input. Playing with itertools I found a solution (posted).

Comment: @Diego welcome so if you find this answer helpful you can tell this to community by voting!

Comment: I voted your answer and also posted the exact code that resolved my problem. Thanks again!